# Phonegap Android 4.4.2 - no suitable egl configs found

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I am getting "No Suitable EGL configs found" error for my Android app right after my splash screen appears and even login page doesn't appear on screen. I have tried adding

```
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

in my manifest file but still not working.
I am facing this issue only with **Android 4.4.2 (on both emulator and my device)**.
Also I am not using any graphics engine. My error log is

```
 02-21 02:30:37.138: W/chromium(1047): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
02-21 02:30:37.158: E/chromium(1047): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-21 02:30:37.158: E/chromium(1047): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-21 02:30:37.158: E/chromium(1047): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-21 02:30:37.158: E/chromium(1047): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-21 02:30:37.168: E/chromium(1047): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I always get these errors while running my app but it never affects my app.

Comment: On Android version 4.4.2 with ARM cpu, my App is not working. Even Phonegap "Hello World" App have same issue with ARM cpu on 4.4.2.